# Testing my own relay without being evil to the network

Tags: exit-relays, bridge

I have implemented some additionnal functionnality to my Tor relay such as more bandwith control than what is possible with the `torrc` configuration file.

Howewer, I would like to try it because this one isn't stable and could crash due to some errors in my code. I firstly thought about bridge, which is nothing more than a private entry node, but it cannot be applied to midde/exit node.

What would be a proper way to test my relay ? How are Tor devs testing their updates ?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure no problem is showing up on the local test - this case you will need to run your own setup on VM's. Rise your own local directories and do the testing. After that - if nothing seems to be broken - safely test it "in vivo" on a real network, I'm doing it myself, no harm done =)